# CSS isn't working in production environment with Laravel Mix 5

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, laravel-mix

This is for my Laravel + Vue SPA app.

I have this Laravel Mix config file here:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
require('laravel-mix-bundle-analyzer');

function publishAssets() {
    const publicDir = path.resolve(__dirname, './public');

    if (mix.inProduction()) {
        fs.removeSync(path.join(publicDir, 'dist'));
    }

    fs.copySync(path.join(publicDir, 'build', 'dist'), path.join(publicDir, 'dist'));
    fs.removeSync(path.join(publicDir, 'build'));
}

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/dist/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/dist/css').options({
        postCss: [tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js')],
        processCssUrls: false,
    });

// alias the ~/resources folder
mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: [
        // new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
    ],

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.vue'],
        alias: {
            '@': `${__dirname}/resources`,
            '~': path.join(__dirname, './resources/js'),
            ziggy: path.join(__dirname, './vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/js/route.js'),
        },
    },

    output: {
        chunkFilename: 'dist/js/[chunkhash].js',
        path: mix.config.hmr ? '/' : path.resolve(__dirname, './public/build'),
    },
});

mix.then(() => {
    if (!mix.config.hmr) {
        process.nextTick(() => publishAssets());
    }
});
```

It works fine with `npm run watch`, but when I do `npm run production`, the CSS doesn't work. The site loads and works, but the CSS is missing.

Can anyone see what in my code is causing it?

Here's my spa.blade.php:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('dist/css/app.css') }}">

...

<script src="{{ mix('dist/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

In the network tab of Chrome dev tools, the CSS file is 270kb in develop environment and 42kb in prod environment.

Something is getting translated wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your issue "the CSS is missing"  "the CSS file is [...] 42kb in prod environment". Do you mean **some** CSS is missing, or you CSS is not loaded?

Comment: What's the entry for app.css file in mix-manifest.json after you run npm run prod? Try loading the app.css without mix helper and check. If it loads correctly that means mix-manifest.json doesn't have the correct entry for app.css

Comment: The css entry is `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/css/app.css">` and in mix-manifest, it is `"/dist/css/app.css": "/dist/css/app.css"`

Comment: And by css is missing, I mean it's not affecting the page's style. It seems to be loaded, and it works in develop env but not production env

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm calling this solved for now because my site started working.

it was extremely difficult to navigate since I had 6 months of work on a dev branch, and it worked via `npm run watch`. When I merged into master, `npm run production` loaded incorrectly--the styles were half there and half missing.

The solution was to downgrade from `tailwindcss@1.9` to `tailwindcss@1.4`.

Along my way, I read something about postcss or something not working with the `--no-progress` flag which is on `npm run production`.

A person could try removing that flag, but I already downgraded tailwind so I didn't try that.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it cause by setting wrong property "purge" in tailwindcss config file.

When I ran "npm run hot" or "npm run dev", the website was fine.
But it broke when I ran "npm run prod".
It seems the dev mode ignore the property "purge".